# Debian - No wired connection after restart

Tags: linux, debian, networking, ipv6, i3

Last night I was working on my computer, for reference I'm using i3, and decided to uninstall XFCE4, as I felt I didn't need it. The next morning I turned on my computer and have no wired connection. I booted onto my windows partition however, and found it did work there. I've looked online but struggled to find any answers.

This is the output of sudo ifconfig:

```
archie@debian:~$ sudo ifconfig
[sudo] password for archie: 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:8d:5c:58:fa:92  
          inet6 addr: fe80::428d:5cff:fe58:fa92/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2061 errors:0 dropped:54 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:307371 (300.1 KiB)  TX bytes:4856 (4.7 KiB)

 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:42 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:42 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:5306 (5.1 KiB)  TX bytes:5306 (5.1 KiB)
```

And this is my /etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

I'm greatful for anyhelp

Comment: Are there any files in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/`? If so, what's their contents?

Comment: Nothing in there... Which I guess is not a good sign?

Comment: It's not a problem. I asked because your interfaces file contains an include statement. If there were any files there, then those would be part of your configuration and it would be important for us to know about them. However, it's not wrong to not have anything there.

Answer (score 1):

Below `auto lo` add `auto eth0`. Then, below that, add `alow-hotplug eth0`

Your final /etc/network/interfaces should read:

```
auto lo
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

Reboot for good measure.

see: `man interfaces` for more info :)

Comment: Unfortunately after editing the file and rebooting I still have no connection :( and my ifconfig looks the same.

Comment: Do you require ipv6 for any specific use cases? If not, change the fourth line to:

`iface eth0 inet dhcp`

If you do require ipv6, add a fifth line:

`iface eth0 inet6 dhcp`

then reboot for good measure

Comment: Ugh, edit limits. I forgot to ask, is the program `resolvconf` installed? If not, you can either install it, or add a sixth line to /etc/network/interfaces:

`dns-nameservers 4.2.2.3 8.8.4.4`

This will use Level3 and Google's DNS servers.

Comment: Combining `auto eth0` and `allow-hotplug eth0` makes no sense. `auto` enables, unconditionally, it at boot; `allow-hotplug` enables it the moment the kernel sees it appear, which is either at boot (for builtin hardware that can't be removed, or for removeable hardware that is plugged in at boot time) or when the hardware is plugged in first. Either of them should be enough.

Comment: The Debian manual states to use both for dhcp: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Using_DHCP_to_automatically_configure_the_interface

I can't be the only person who occasionally hot swaps patch cables.

Comment: Again I followed all of these instructions but still no connection :( Resolvconf was not installed.

Comment: @WilliamBonney the wiki is not the manual. Users using the wiki have been known to make mistakes... the manual is found by way of `man 5 interfaces`.